# Last member of vector does not give proper result in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have a vector named :

```
ts<- c(1.061786, 1.201682, 1.265509, 1.372124, 1.572853, 1.629114, 1.660798, 1.898390, 1.908208, 1.944675)
```

. Now I want to make another vector from this one which gives the difference between consecutive members. And for the last value (ts[10]); the difference would be from a double "T".

The code is as follows:

```
cppFunction("
 std::vector<double> res (std::vector<double> ts, double T ){

          std::vector<double> newts(ts.size()+1);
          newts[0]=0.0;
          for(int j=1; j<=ts.size(); j++){
            if(j< ts.size()){
            newts[j]= ts[j]-ts[j-1];
            }
             else if (j== ts.size()){
            newts[j]= T -ts[j];
             }
             else{
                newts[j]=0.0;
             }
          }

        return newts;
        }
        ")
```

.
The actual result for res(ts,T=2) should be like:

```
    [1] 0.000000000 0.139895661 0.063826732 0.106615236 0.200729464 0.056260681 0.031683749 0.237591892
    [9] 0.009818105 0.036467479 0.05532473
```

. But it is giving me the result:

```
 [1] 0.000000000 0.139895661 0.063826732 0.106615236 0.200729464 0.056260681 0.031683749 0.237591892
 [9] 0.009818105 0.036467479 2.000000000
```

That is the last member of the new vector is not correct. Why is this happening? Any suggestion?

**Edit**

Even if I use the following code :

```
cppFunction("
 std::vector<double> res (std::vector<double> ts, double T ){

          std::vector<double> newts(ts.size()+1);

          for(int j=0; j<=ts.size(); j++){
            if(j==0){
              newts[j]=0.0;
            }
            else if(j< ts.size()){
            newts[j]= ts[j]-ts[j-1];
            }
             else if (j== ts.size()){
            newts[j]= T -ts[j];
             }
             else{
                newts[j]=0.0;
             }
          }

        return newts;
        }
        ")
```

, it still gives me the wrong result.

Comment: Valid indices in c++ go from _0 - size - 1_. Your `for()` loop header is wrong.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I did not understand. Could you please explain?

Comment: Yoiu should replace `for(int j=1; j<=ts.size(); j++){` with `for(int j=0; j<ts.size(); j++){`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But I already defined the newts[0] before the for loop

Comment: `j<=ts.size()` would be still wrong though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and according to your suggestion, even if I enter the newts[0] member inside the for loop, it gives me wrong result

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Note that he has defined newts with size = ts.size() + 1 ...

so looping through j = 1 to j <= ts.size() is still correct

Answer (score 0):

It's better to start from the tail of the vector

```
std::vector<double> res(std::vector<double> ts, double T) {

    std::vector<double> newts(ts.size() + 1);
    newts[0] = 0.0;
    int n = ts.size();
    for (int j = n - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        newts[j] = ts[j] - ts[j - 1];
    }

    newts[newts.size() - 1] = T - ts[n - 1];

    return newts;
}
```

And here's the derived program

```
int main() {
    std::vector<double> ts{ 1.061786, 1.201682, 1.265509, 1.372124, 1.572853, 1.629114, 1.660798, 1.898390, 1.908208, 1.944675 };
    double T = 2;
    std::vector<double> result = res(ts, T);

    for (auto x : result)
        std::cout << x << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alright, I found the solution. Just entered the double "T" inside the "ts" vector.

```
cppFunction("
 std::vector<double> res (std::vector<double> ts, double T ){

          std::vector<double> newts(ts.size()+1);
          newts=ts;
          newts.insert(newts.end(),T);
          std::vector<double> nnewts(newts.size());
          for(int j=0; j<newts.size(); j++){
            if(j==0){
              nnewts[j]=0.0;
            }
            else if(j< newts.size()){
            nnewts[j]= newts[j]-newts[j-1];
            }

             else{
                nnewts[j]=0.0;
             }
          }

        return nnewts;
        }
        ")
```

Comment: How is this a solution?  You still access the vector out of bounds here: `else if(j<= newts.size()){ nnewts[j]= newts[j]-newts[j-1];`.  Accessing a vector out-of-bounds is *undefined behavior* meaning anything can happen. Adding `T` does nothing except mask the existing bug you have now.  If you need to be convinced, change `nnewts[j]= newts[j]-newts[j-1];` to `nnewts.at(j) = newts.at(j) - newts.at(j-1);`. When `j` is `newts.size()`, an `out_of_range` exception will be thrown.